# Taking function inputs as literals, similar to a bash script

Tags: python

Does anyone know if there is an analog to the bash script way of taking variables as literal? For example, any way I'd be able to do:

`type = log` or `type = sqrt`

then

```
var_transformed = np.$type(data)
```

which would be literally interpreted as the user being able to specify the function in place of `$type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects and can be assigned to variables. When you omit the parentheses you get the function itself without calling it and then can call it later.

```
func = np.log
var_transformed = func(data)
```